# select child that follows current tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a heading  that is followed by a div which I want to show when the h2 is clicked...

```
<h2><a href="#">Some Tag</a></h2>
<div>content here</div>

<h2><a href="#">Some  other  Tag</a></h2>
<div>content here</div>

<h2><a href="#">Some  other  Tag</a></h2>
<div>content here</div>
```

How do I select the div that follows the h2 I clicked on?

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h2').click(function(e){
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
display:none;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qJUQj/